# Скрыть / показать несколько блоков по классу JS

Tags: javascript, html

помогите пожалуйста доработать текущий код. Нужно чтобы по клику на элемент, скрывались-показывались элементы с одним классом

```
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <span class="hide_btn">Показать опции</span>

    <div class="content hidden">Товарищи! постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений.</div>
    <div class="content hidden">Постоянное! постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений.</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const btn = document.querySelector('.hide_btn')
        const content = document.querySelector('.content')

        btn.addEventListener('click', btnClick)

        function btnClick() {
            if (content.classList.contains('hidden')) {
                btn.textContent = 'Скрыть опции'
            } else {
                btn.textContent = 'Показать опции'
            }

            content.classList.toggle('hidden')
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, конечно, но querySelectorAll не работает в данном случае

Comment: Так и пишет: "Я не работаю"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(c => c.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

вместо строчки

```
content.classList.toggle('hidden')
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать весь код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @AndreyK. Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: Прошу извинить, но скажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли сделать чтобы работало несколько кнопок "скрыть/показать"?

Comment: @AndreyK. Все можно, но мне по проводам плохо видны Ваши мысли.

Comment: <span class="hide_btn">Показать опции</span>
    <span class="hide_btn">Показать опции</span>
Чтобы по клику на эти оба span показывались / скрывались все элементы

Comment: Сейчас работает только первый

Comment: @AndreyK. Вы уже знаете про `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Да, знаю. Но он опять не работает( если я напишу так:    const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.hide_btn')